# Let $F$ be an ordered field in which every strictly monotone increasing sequence bounded above converges. Prove that $F$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis

I know that an ordered field is complete if it has the monotonic sequence property (every monotone increasing sequence bounded above converges). So I'm not sure if this knowledge is enough to prove that $F$ is complete. How else would I go about proving this?

Comment: What kind of "completion" do you want?  What do you mean by "complete"?  Cheers!

Comment: Since ["complete" means "has the monotone convergence property"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers), the proof is trivial!  More seriously, to make your question well-defined, you need to say what *other* statement of completeness you are trying to prove that the monotone sequence property implies.  (or a list, if you'll accept a proof of any one of them)

Comment: @RobertLewis.  My guess is that  the proposer wants to show that if every bounded increasing sequence converges then every non-empty bounded subset has a $lub$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A monotone increasing sequence either is eventually constant (thus convergent) or has a strictly monotone increasing subsequence. If that subsequence converges, then by monotonicity it is not hard to see that the entire sequence converges.

So if every strictly monotone increasing bounded above sequence converges, then every monotone bounded above sequence converges.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!